# using android:layout_gravity

Tags: android-widget

i am new to android development. I want to know how to use the attribute **android:layout_gravity** and can i use this option to position a view at center of the screen width.??

I tried the following but it's aligning at top

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Table Layout" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:hint="username" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:hint="password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="SAVE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="CANCLE" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

and my output is :

[image: output]

Comment: Where is your textview contained? Post the full layout code.

Comment: I posted my full layout code(xml file)... Iam trying to add layout_gravity for first textview with id @+id/textview

Comment: That can't be your full layout code, you have multiple root elements, and TableRows are meant to be used inside a TableLayout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android there is

`android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity`

**android:gravity** - *Is used to move the content of the View or Layout to which this property is set.*
**android:layout_gravity** - *Is used to move the View or Layout itself to any position.*

Here is a nice demo and explanation of how it works.

[gravity and layout_gravity](http://www.gibby.net.au/android/android-gravity-vs-layout_gravity/)

Comment: Thanks.... please can you provide me a bit more details about android:layout_gravity. Their options and usage.

Comment: Pleas look at the link that I provided now after editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="0.5"
   android:text="CANCEL" 
   android:gravity="LEFT"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
/>
```

Comment: here the text "CANCEL" will move to left in the button.